# How to rewrite query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am getting the `rewrite the query in a form that can be translated` error when trying to run a entity framework query with a `Include` and `ThenInclude` clause. All this code was working before the application was moved from Microsoft.EntityFramework version 3.1 to Microsoft.EntityFramework version 5.0.4.

[image]

What could I be missing?

```
internal IEnumerable<ProductHierarchy> ProductHierarchiesWithDetail
  get
  {
    var item = ProductHierarchies.Include(x => X.BusinessAssocs).ThenInclude(x => X.Business).AsEnumerable();
    return item; 
  }
}
public class ProductHierarchy
{
  public Uri ProductHierarchyURI { get; set; }
  public IList<HierarchyBusinessAssoc> BusinessAssocs{ get; set; } = new List<HierarchyBusinessAssoc>();
}

public class Hierarchy BusinessAssoc
{
  public Uri ProducthierarchyURI { get; set; }
  public Uri BusinessURI { get; set; }
  public ProductHierarchy Hierarchy { get; set; }
  public Business Business { get; set; }
}

public class Business
{
  public Uri BusinessURI { get; set; }
  public IList<HierarchyBusinessAssoc> HierarchyAssocs { get; set; } = new List<HierarchyBusinessAssoc>();
  public IList<ProductType> ProductTypes { get; set; } = new List<ProductType>();
}

public class ProductHierarchyEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ProductHierarchy>
{
public void configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ProductHierarchy> builder)
{
  builder. Totable("ProductHierarchy");
  builder.Haskey(e => new { e.ProducthierarchyURI });
  builder.HasMany(x => x.BusinessAssocs).WithOne (assoc => assoc.Hierarchy);
}

public class HierarchyBusinessAssocEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<HierarchyBusinessAssoc>
{
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<HierarchyBusinessAssoc> builder)
  {
    builder.ToTable("ProductHieracyBusinessAssociation");
    builder.Haskey(e => new { e.producthierarchyURI, e.BusinessURI });
    builder.Hasone (assoc => assoc.Hierarchy).WithMany (h => h.BusinessAssocs).HasForeignKey(assoc => assoc.ProductHierarchyURI);
    builder.HasOne (assoc => assoc. Business).WithMany (ph => ph.HierarchyAssocs).HasForeignKey(x => x.BusinessURI);
  }
}

public class BusinessEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Business>
{
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Business> builder)
  {
    builder.ToTable("Business");
    builder.Haskey(e => new {e.BusinessURI});
    builder.HasMany (pt => pt.HierarchyAssocs).WithOne(x => x.Business).HasForeignKey(x => x.BusinessURI);
  }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<HierarchyBusinessAssoc> 0.Where(h => EF.Property<Uri> (EntityShaperExpression:Entity Type: ProductHierarchyValueBufferExpression:
ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjection MemberIsNullable: False
,"ProductHierarchyURI") != null && object.Equals(objA: EF.Property<Uri> (EntityShaperExpression:
EntityType: ProductHierarchyValueBufferExpression:ProjectionBindingExpression: Empty Projection MemberIsNullable: False,"ProductHierarchyURI"), objB: EF.Property<Uri>(h, "ProductHierarchyURI")))
Join
inner: DbSet<Business> 0.outerKeySelector: h => EF.Property<Uri>(h, "BusinessURI"),
innerKeySelector: b => EF.Property<Uri>(b, "BusinessURI"),
resultSelector: (0, 1) => new TransparentIdentifier<HierarchyBusinessAssoc, Business>
Outer = 0,Inner = i' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.
```

Comment: This seems to be Uri mapping related InMemory provider bug (does not happen with SqlServer) . Happens also in the latest official at this time 5.0.7. There is nothing we can do to help, please go to https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues

Comment: Or don't use `Uri` type, replace it with `string`.